# Center DIV containing elements with display absolute

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, css-position, absolute

I'm trying to replicate the following design in react:
[image]

Here's what I've currently got:
[image]

Here's the code for it:

```
import React, {  useState } from "react";
import "./DisplayCards.css";

type DisplayCardsProps = {
  images: string[];
  group: number;
};

const DisplayCards: React.FC<DisplayCardsProps> = ({ images, group }) => {
  const [currentGroup, setCurrentGroup] = useState(0);
  const startIndex = currentGroup * group;

  const firstGroup = images.slice(0, startIndex);
  const secondGroup = images.slice(startIndex, startIndex + group);
  const thirdGroup = images.slice(startIndex + group);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main-cards">
        {secondGroup.map((name, index) => {
          return (
            <img
              key={index}
              src={name}
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>

      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            setCurrentGroup((prevGroup) =>
              thirdGroup.length !== 0 ? prevGroup + 1 : prevGroup
            )
          }
        >
          Shift Group Forward
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            setCurrentGroup((prevGroup) =>
              firstGroup.length !== 0 ? prevGroup - 1 : prevGroup
            )
          }
        >
          Shift Group Backward
        </button>
      </div>
      <div style={{ padding: "200px" }}></div>

      <div className="grid-container">
        <div className="first-group">
          {firstGroup.map((name, index) => {
            return (
              <img
                key={index}
                src={name}
                width={157}
                height={219}
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  left: `${10 * index}px`,
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>

        <div className="third-group">
          {thirdGroup.map((name, index) => {
            return (
              <img
                key={index}
                src={name}
                width={157}
                height={219}
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  left: `${10 * index}px`,
                  marginLeft: "500px",
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DisplayCards;
```

And the CSS:

```css
.main-cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space;
}
```

I can't figure out how to center the cards on the bottom. Also, the cards on top are three images on top of each other. I tried spreading them out with:

```
        {secondGroup.map((name, index) => {
          return (
            <img
              key={index}
              src={name}
              width={157}
              height={219}
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                left: `${30 * index}px`,
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
```

Which kind of worked, but it wasn't centered perfectly. It was off by like 50px or something. How can I center all the cards and display them like shown in the design I'm trying to replicate?

Last question, when I'm moving the cards forward (i.e., clicking the `Shift Group Forward` button), how can I make the left stack of cards grow backward like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Efr9z4jdLso&t=20s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got everything working. I don't know what I really changed (mostly because I did a lot of changes), but here's the final code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaArrowLeft, FaArrowRight } from "react-icons/fa";
import { BiChevronsLeft, BiChevronsRight } from "react-icons/bi";

import Button from "../Button";

import "./DisplayCards.css";

type DisplayCardsProps = {
  images: string[];
  group: number;
  data: any;
};

const DisplayCards: React.FC<DisplayCardsProps> = ({ images, group, data }) => {
  const [currentGroup, setCurrentGroup] = useState(0);
  const startIndex = currentGroup * group;

  const firstGroup = images.slice(0, startIndex);
  const secondGroup = images.slice(startIndex, startIndex + group);
  const thirdGroup = images.slice(startIndex + group);

  let margin: string;
  if (data["cardSpacing"] == "regular") margin = "-125px";
  else margin = "-175px";

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="first-section">
        <div className="button">
          <Button
            icon={<FaArrowLeft />}
            className="arrow"
            onClick={() =>
              setCurrentGroup((prevGroup) =>
                firstGroup.length !== 0 ? prevGroup - 1 : prevGroup
              )
            }
          />
        </div>

        <div className="main-cards">
          {secondGroup.map((name, index) => {
            return (
              <img
                key={index}
                src={name}
                style={{
                  marginLeft: index == 0 ? "0px" : margin,
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>

        <div className="button">
          <Button
            icon={<FaArrowRight />}
            className="arrow"
            onClick={() =>
              setCurrentGroup((prevGroup) =>
                thirdGroup.length !== 0 ? prevGroup + 1 : prevGroup
              )
            }
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="second-section">
        <div className="first-cards" style={{
          marginLeft: firstGroup.length !== 0 ? "0px" : "110px",
        }}>
          {firstGroup.map((name, index) => {
            return (
              <img
                key={index}
                src={name}
                width={157}
                height={219}
                style={{
                  marginLeft: index == 0 ? "0px" : "-145px",
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>

        {thirdGroup.length !== 0 && (
          <div className="third-cards">
            {thirdGroup.map((name, index) => {
              return (
                <img
                  key={index}
                  src={name}
                  width={157}
                  height={219}
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: index == 0 ? "0px" : "-145px",
                  }}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="third-section"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DisplayCards;
```

And here's the CSS:

```css
.first-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.second-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.third-cards {
  margin-left: -110px;
}

.arrow {
  padding: 0.78571429em 1.5em 0.78571429em;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 0.28571429rem;
  background-color: var(--button-ok-background-color);
  color: var(--button-ok-text-color);
}
```

Here's how it looks:
[image: final showcase]